# PIL not reading tkFileDialog?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
files = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(mode='rb',filetypes=fileTypes,initialdir = direc,multiple=False,parent = root,title = 'Choose an Image')
    framing = Toplevel()
    framing.title("Framing Menu")
    scroll = Scrollbar(framing)
    scroll.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
    imLabel = Label(framing)
    imLabel.pack(side=RIGHT)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(files))
    imlabel2 = Label(framing,image=image)
    imlabel2.image = image
    imlabel2.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

When I use a file dialog to get a file from the user, and try to open it using PIL, I get this error:

```
IOError: cannot identify image file <open file u'C:/Users/Alec/Pictures/california-county-map.gif', mode 'r' at 0x000000000A93A030>
```

california-county-map.gif was the test picture I was using, and PIL apparently can't read it, what's going on here?

Comment: Try if you can read the image by PIL: `PIL.Image.open(files)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` is expecting a file name and instead it got an open file, so just change:

```
ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(files))
```

to:

```
ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=files) #need the 'file=' to specify you are using an already opened file
```

EDIT:

An alternate solution is to get the file name from the user, then open the file with `PIL` you would need to use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile`:

```
files = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(filetypes=fileTypes,initialdir = direc,multiple=False,parent = root,title = 'Choose an Image')
...
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open(files))
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, and that did fix part of the issue, but I get a new error: 'KeyError: <open file u'C:/Users/Alec/Pictures/california-county-map.gif', mode 'r' at 0x000000000A93A300>'

Comment: My bad, needed the `file=` keyword to specify that the image needs to be created using the already opened file

Answer (score 0):

As said in [Here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageTk.html),
you can do ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename, size=None, **kw). So you could get the filename first:

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
from PIL import ImageTk
root = Tkinter.Tk()
fileTypes = [ ('All','*'), ("GIF","*.gif")]
filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=fileTypes,initialdir = 't:/',multiple=False,parent = root,title = 'Choose an Image')
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage( file = filename)
```